# Jade/Pug mixin extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've started to use Jade at work and I met a problem for which I couldn't find an answer to on Google.

I want write such a mixin:

```
mixin menu(...MenuList) 
  ul.main-menu
    each item in MenuList
      li: a(href='##{item.toLowerCase()}.html')= item
```

This mixin works well for single name links like `+menu('Contacts', 'FAQ')`, but doesn't work for multi-word links like `+menu('Contact Us', 'Our Price')`.

I tried to write something like:

```
li: a(href='##{item.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')}.html')= item
```

or:

```
li: a(href='##{item.toLowerCase(function(x){ return x.replace(' ', '_')})}.html')= item
```

but nothing works for me. Maybe it's the lack of JS skills, but I would be happy if somebody could help me.

Comment: What is the expected name? `our_price.html`?

Comment: Yes, Ryan! Instead of gap I want inset _

Comment: So was the issue with your first attempt (`item.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')`) that it only replaced one space, or did something else go wrong?

Comment: If I use only .toLowerCase() it works properly: render 'our product.html', but it has gap, when I add .replace, it renders 'item.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')'.   It render function in string.

Comment: Oh, that’d be the quotes. Use double quotes to avoid conflicting with the surroundings, and `.replace(/ /g, '_')` to replace all instances instead of just the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the way you pass in the href. Here's a working one and [Codepen.io link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLWMQM?editors=1000)

```
mixin menu(...MenuList)
  - var patt = /\s+/i; // This checks for whitespace.

  ul.main-menu
    each item in MenuList
     if patt.test(item)
       - var newitem = item.split(' ').join('_');

       li: a&attributes({ href: '#' + newitem.toLowerCase() + '.html' })= item
     else
       li: a&attributes({ href: '#' + item.toLowerCase() + '.html' })= item

+menu('my-list', 'Contact Us', 'Hello', 'Our Price', 'My Price')

// result
- my-list
- Contact Us
- Hello
- Our Price
- My Price
```

Comment: Thank you for response! But it was working before. The question was how to deal with gap between words, coz I get our price.html instead of our_price.html

Comment: Oh gotcha looking into that

Comment: @DmitriyKavraiskyi I have updated the answer and codepen as well. Hopes this helps

Comment: Oh, man thanks! That it is what I was looking for! 

Also, I have a bit change it, coz there is no need in an gap:

- var replace = item.split(' ').join('_');
       li: a&attributes({ href: '#' + replace.toLowerCase() + '.html' })= item

Comment: @DmitriyKavraiskyi Cheers.